# Presigned URL generation code times-out as Lambda, works locally

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, pre-signed-url

I use a proxy - using the `aws-lambda-fastify` package to make my Fastify based REST API work under AWS Lambda.

One of the issues, which I had to solve to run under Lambda, was HTTP requests timing out. It turned out to have been caused by the event loop not being empty. I had to set a special flag on the Lambda `context` and now requests return fine, all except for one - a route to generate pre-signed URLs for S3 upload.

```
const S3 = require('aws-sdk/clients/s3');

module.exports = createPresignedPost = ({ key, contentType }) => {
  const s3 = new S3();
  s3.config.accessKeyId = process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY;
  s3.config.secretAccessKey = process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY;
  s3.config.region = process.env.AWS_REGION;
  const params = {
    Expires: 60,
    Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
    Conditions: [['content-length-range', 100, 10000000]], // 100Byte - 10MB
    Fields: {
      'Content-Type': contentType,
      'Cache-Control': 'max-age=31536000',
      key
    }
  };
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    s3.createPresignedPost(params, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
        return;
      }
      resolve(data);
    });
  });
};
```

This function causes a time-out when invoked from/under Lambda, while it is performing perfectly fine locally under Docker and/or virtual/physical hosts.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the lambda function associated with a VPC?

Comment: @Marcin what is the difference? clearly, on a host `s3.createPresignedPost()` returns and under Lambda it does not.

Comment: Lambda in VPC does not have internet connection by default. So you will time out if you want to access S3, unless you setup your VPC and lambda correctly.

Comment: I am connecting from that Lambda to RDS [in the same region as Lambda and S3], so the lack of connectivity is not the problem, I believe.

Comment: Is it public RDS, or you made a private RDS in a private subnet and you connected lambda to that subnet to interact with the RDS?

Comment: I connect using a public FQDN

Comment: There is a typo here, I don't know if it can cause this problem:   s3.config.accessKeyId = process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.update({
  region: process.env.AWS_DEFAULT_REGION,
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
  }
});

module.exports = createPresignedPost = ({ key, contentType }) => {
  const s3 = new AWS.S3();
  const params = {
    Expires: 60,
    Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
    Conditions: [['content-length-range', 100, 10000000]], // 100Byte - 10MB
    Fields: {
      'Content-Type': contentType,
      'Cache-Control': 'max-age=31536000',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      key
    }
  };

  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    s3.createPresignedPost(params, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
      resolve(data);
    });
  });
};
```